# Separate tags for Sibelius (composer/software)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Having asked a question about Sibelius 7 software recently, I noticed that the Sibelius tag is used for the composer and the software. Would it be useful to have, for example, "Sibelius (composer)" and "Sibelius (software)"? I haven't done any tag editing yet (not sure I can anyway), so just wondered how these tags would best be set up, and how the questions might then be reallocated. I'm guessing this is the opposite of the tag synonym process.

Comment: Should we have a tag for a specific musician or composer?

Comment: Ah yes, I was wondering about that too, and understand why you raise the question. I'll have a look and see which ones are reasonably well used so far. Most composers/musicians wouldn't raise the specific problem Sibelius presents though...

Comment: But it goes along with the topic. If we need to tag composers and musicians then it is an issue and we should probably make a new tag. If we don't we just remove the Sibelius tag from questions with the composer Sibelius.

Comment: Right, I understand your thinking. That would make sense. Also a clear Sibelius tag wiki (if there isn't one) and possibly renaming it "Sibelius (software)" might help. Thanks for your advice, Dom. I'm still learning the ropes...

Comment: Okay, @Dom, it would seem that your first comment (above) actually raises a more important point than my actual question. Besides Sibelius, there are only four other composers with tags (Bach, Beethoven, Mozart and Chopin), so it may not actually need dealing with though. (But if it does, I think your comment itself would make a cogent meta question.) I just checked, and the Sibelius tag wiki clearly refers to the software, so I think it should be renamed, to be even more clear, and posts referring to the composer should have this tag removed.